# Verify a message was sent by Google by comaparing x-goog-signature to a generated signature

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

In NodeJS I'm trying to verify a message was sent by Google before processing the message contents.

This is done by comparing the message header "x-goog-signature" to a generated signature.

The generated signature code takes as input the service account key and the http raw body.

Following this [example](https://github.com/google-business-communications/bm-nodejs-echo-bot/blob/master/message_validation_sample/routes/index.js).

```js
let generatedSignature = require('crypto').createHmac('sha512', partnerKey).update(Buffer.from(req.rawBody, 'utf8')).digest('base64');
```

This is the key from which I parse the `private_key` value.

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "XXXX",
  "private_key_id": "XXXXXXX",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXXXXXXXXXX\nXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "XXXX",
  "client_id": "XXXXXXX",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/dev-gary%40asc-gbm-registration-proj.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

And getting raw body from httpRequest.

`httpRequest.rawBody`

But the resulting generated signature is not the same as the x-goog-signature.

The `private_key` value has a prefix and postfix which I've removed. Also tried without the `\n` newline chars.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not work with Google Business Communications so these are tips: 1) Do not remove the prefix, postfix, or \n characters. 2) Signatures are verified using the public key and not the private key. Signatures are created with the private key. Your service account JSON key contains the public certificate link **client_x509_cert_url**.  3) Make sure you are using the correct HMAC algorithm. Google typically uses SHA256, the example uses SHA512 which might be correct. 4) Edit your question and include https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you're referring to seems to answer your question with a link:

```
/**
 * Verify the message is from Google.
 * Learn more in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/business-communications/business-messages/guides/build/receive#verify).
 *
 * @param {string} message The message text received from the user.
 * @param {string} conversationId The unique id for this user and agent.
 */
function validateMessage(message, conversationId) {}
```

The link is just meanwhile: https://developers.google.com/business-communications/business-messages/guides/how-to/message/receive#verify.
There's even a precise example, but I cannot find where it validates the `X-Goog-Signature` header: https://github.com/google-business-communications/bm-nodejs-echo-bot/tree/master/message_validation_sample

And I also think it's HMAC / SHA256 / Base64 - but the docs explicitly say SHA512 (it wouldn't hurt to try both). Also the header string matters; the input string must be processed exactly alike the server-side did it, else the comparison won't match.

```
let generatedSignature = require('crypto')
    .createHmac('sha512', partnerKey)
    .update(Buffer.from(req.rawBody, 'utf8'))
    .digest('base64');
```

That "partnerKey" likely is not a service-account credentials JSON (not sure what they've sent):

> After Google registers your project, Google sends you a confirmation email with your partner information, including a Partner ID and an Partner key (formerly "CRM key" or "authorization key").

It is probably save to assume, that this confirmation email holds the key to the solution.

Comment: Indeed the correct key is the partner key (not the service account key) which was sent when we registered with Google Business Messages. The code from Google example works out of the box with the correct key.